# How to allow API Gateway to return a 405 response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

Hello AWS Cloud Gurus,

I am trying to allow my REST API to return a 405 when an unsupported HTTP verb is used on any resource.

I see there are ways to define [GatewayResponses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html).

However, I don't see any obvious approach to return a 405 (other than to define it as the `DEFAULT_4XX` which seems incorrect)

```
  ExampleApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      OpenApiVersion: '3.0.1'
      GatewayResponses:
        DEFAULT_4XX:
          StatusCode: 405
          ResponseTemplates:
            "application/*": '{ "message": "Method Not Allowed" }'
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a lambda function, attached to the API, to handle a specific endpoint which needs to indicate 405

```
  ExampleApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      OpenApiVersion: '3.0.1'

  MethodNotAllowedResponse:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Handler: index.handler
      InlineCode: |
        let response;
        exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
          response = {
            "statusCode": 405,
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/problem+json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
              "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6",
              "status": 405,
              "title": "Method Not Allowed",
              "detail": `Method ${event.httpMethod} is not allowed on ${event.path}`
            })
            }
          callback(null, response);
        }
      Events:
        Televisions:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
            RestApiId: !Ref ExampleApi
            Path: '/not/allowed/path'
            Method: patch
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement:

- return response for GET method
- return 405 for any other HTTP method.

I've solved it following way:

#1 added to my resource in **API Gateway** method **ANY** (in addition to already existed **GET** method)

- Then for **ANY** method `Integration Response -> Mapping Templates -> New template application/json`
- Added following code to template:
  `#set($context.responseOverride.status = 405)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented as a mock integration that you then use for any methods that are not implemented/supported.

Integration request mapping

```
{
  "statusCode": 405,
  "message": "The invoked method is not supported on the API resource."
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, so for every endpoint I have a GET for, I would define mock integrations for all the other verbs (e.g PUT, PATCH, etc) just to return a 405?

Comment: Yep. I haven’t included the response template but it should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: @jakebrinkmann - Stack overflow [does not work like a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110), so you should add that to your question, or ask another question, not add it to an answer.